# Advices in error logs

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

We're using java + hibernate + c3p0. In some cases there is such error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet successfully received from the server was 70,401,557 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

But in others cases this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 43,974,672 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 43,974,674 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

It seems that these are equal errors. Why in the second log message advice is printed:

```
 is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

The c3p0 configuration is

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"> 
    <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver_class}" /> 
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" /> 
    <property name="user" value="${database.username}" /> 
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" /> 
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="600" /> 
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="28790" /> 
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your c3p0 config?

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${database.driver_class}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="600" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="28790" />
    </bean>

Comment: `Why in the second log message advice is printed` because the failures are detected at different spots and the log message coded into the two spots is different.

Comment: Try to add http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#testConnectionOnCheckout parameter to pool config.